# Calculate height for empty tableview

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm having problem in getting a height of empty tableview and my response sometimes is null and I'm storing it in array so basically my array is empty (NULL),so as we know tableview first of all calculates the height of its cell so my program is getting crash ...

> {Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'}

I know this is happening because i'm calculating height when i have data in array.So as when there is no data in array i'm showing a cell from xib and i have to calculate the height of this cell also...
how can I achieve this ...

Comment: In what method to you do it? Awake from nib?

Comment: No hieght for row at indexpath

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the array is null

```
if(array){
 //return the height of the view from XIB
}else{
 //return the calculated height
}
```

Comment: No actually array is null  so it'll not return any index..It's crashing though i had already done it

Comment: By null do you mean that it has not been initialized?

Comment: Okey i found the solution anyway thnxx